# Any logging utility which dynamically change error level (if logging an eror then output debug logs as well)

Tags: c#, logging

We have an in-house logging utility (in C++) which has a very nice feature which I have no seen in any of the logging utilities I have looked at but maybe there is (or some plugin).

Most loggers will have a setting which level of log information should be saved for example log warnings or worse.

In many code bases you have a bunch of debug info as well. Those are very useful to track down any problems. But normally you do not output those until you explictly turn it on.

The feature I am looking for is what we have in our logging utility: If we log an error it will then automatically also write the previous X debug/info logs even if we are using a log level which suppress debug logs

This is very useful when you get an exception which might be hard to reproduce. Those debug logs which would otherwise be suppressed is very useful in this case. But during normal operations those debug logs are to much "spam".